# SQL Server authentication in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, authentication

I created a login with SQL authentication credential in SQL Server 2008. But, I am not able to login using that credential.

We followed the same steps in SQL Server 2005 and working without any problem.

What could be the problem?

Thanks,
P.Gopalakrishnan.

Comment: do you get an error? if so - what is it?

Comment: Yes, I am getting the following error.

Login Failed for user (username). Error 18456

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked that SQL Server Authentication is enabled?  It is disabled by default.  From SQL Server Management Studio, right-click your server, Properties, Security, SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode.

Answer (score 0):

have you confirmed that you are logging into the correct instance of sql server on the machine that you created the login for?

Comment: Yes, I confirmed. I am using the correct instance of sql server in which the new login created.